# Allow to change bounty value at the third step of the Create Bounty dialog

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-dialog

Say, you want to start a bounty. Whatever amount of reputation you want to offer, it is totally imaginable you can change your mind and offer more, or less, whatever. It's important, that's why it is explicitely mentioned in the last step of the create bounty dialog:

[image]

The thing is that if you answer to the question stated, that is to "Are you sure you want to start a bounty of  reputation on this question" - if you answer is "actually I'm not sure" you have no option other than to click twice to be back to the first step and click twice to be back. So why not make it possible to change the value exactly in the question?

Here's what I propose:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not that I don't understand your request, but I don't think it is that necessary because

1. There are only three steps, i.e., (1) select reputation from 10 choices (from 50 to 500), (2) click an answer to the question "Why are you starting this bounty?" and (3) enter a custom message.
2. The third step is just optional and you don't even have to write anything there.
3. Even if you write something in the blank box, it won't be erased even if you click on the *back* button. Nothing changes including your answer in the second step.

Therefore, you can just click *back* twice if you want to change the reputation and continue to click *next*, *next* and *start bounty*. I've just started a bounty to see how it works again and it doesn't take longer than a few seconds.

Comment: clicking back twice and clicking next twice is bearable but can be avoided pretty easily, so why just not?

Comment: @shabunc If you are not sure about the reputation point you want to offer as a bounty, why do you offer a bounty in the first place? You can decide the rep amount first and proceed. It isn't that there is nothing you can do when you have a second thought.

Comment: there's a reason why this question is placed there - that actually means that it's important.

Comment: @shabunc I expressed my opinion. Others might differ. I don't think it is that important.